# What are the difference between `property.[]` and `property` in computed properties

Tags: javascript, ember.js

With **ember.js**, using computed properties, I can use either this:

```js
myProp: computed('properties', function () { /* do stuff. */ });
```

Or this:

```js
myProp: computed('properties.[]', function () { /* do stuff. */ });
```

What are the difference between these two approach? Which one should I use in what situation?

Comment: Did you read https://guides.emberjs.com/release/object-model/computed-properties-and-aggregate-data/ ?

Comment: @str No, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first (`properties`) just watches `properties`. So it will invalidate when you do `this.set('properties', ...)`.

The second is for arrays and will invalidate when you remove or add items for arrays:

```
this.set('properties', ...);
this.properties.pushObject(...);
this.properties.popObject(...);
```

So when you just do `'properties'` it will not invalidate when you add or remove something from the array.